# Taylor expansion about candidate point $x^*$: $f(x^∗ + h) = f(x^∗) + hf'(x^∗) + O(h^2)$?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, taylor-expansion

My textbook, *Algorithms for Optimization*, by Kochenderfer and Wheeler, says the following:

> A point can also be at a local minimum if it has a zero derivative and the second derivative is merely nonnegative:
>
> 1. $f'(x^∗) = 0$, the *first-order necessary condition* (FONC)
> 2. $f''(x^∗) \ge 0$, the *second-order necessary condition* (SONC)
>
> These conditions are referred to as necessary because all local minima obey these two rules. Unfortunately, not all points with a zero derivative and a zero second derivative are local minima, as demonstrated in figure 1.7.
>
> The first necessary condition can be derived using the Taylor expansion about our candidate point $x^*$:
>
> $$f(x^∗ + h) = f(x^∗) + hf'(x^∗) + O(h^2)$$
> $$f(x^∗ − h) = f(x^∗) − hf'(x^∗) + O(h^2)$$
> $$f(x^∗ + h) \ge f(x^∗) \Rightarrow hf'(x^∗) \ge 0$$
> $$f(x^∗ − h) \ge f(x^∗) \Rightarrow hf'(x^∗) \le 0$$
> $$\Rightarrow f'(x^∗)=0$$

Appendix C states the Taylor expansion about $a$ as

> $$f(x) \approx f(a) + f'(a)(x - a) + \dfrac{1}{2} f''(a)(x - a)^2$$

So if we want the Taylor expansion about our candidate point $x^*$, as the textbook states, then we have

$$f(x) \approx f(x^*) + f'(x^*)(x - x^*) + \dfrac{1}{2} f''(x^*)(x - x^*)^2,$$

which is not $f(x^∗ + h) = f(x^∗) + hf'(x^∗) + O(h^2)$.

Or if we set $x = x^* + h$, we get

$$f(x^* + h) \approx f(a) + f'(a)(x^* + h - a) + \dfrac{1}{2} f''(a)(x^* + h - a)^2,$$

which is not $f(x^∗ + h) = f(x^∗) + hf'(x^∗) + O(h^2)$.

Or if we set $x = x^* + h$ and take the Taylor expansion about $h$ (rather than $x^*$ as was stated), we get

$$f(x^* + h) \approx f(h) + f'(h)(x^*) + \dfrac{1}{2} f''(h)(x^*)^2,$$

which is not $f(x^∗ + h) = f(x^∗) + hf'(x^∗) + O(h^2)$.

So I'm confused as to how the authors' result makes sense? I would greatly appreciate it if someone would please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried
$$x=x^*+h, a=x^*$$?

Comment: Ahh, that's it. Thanks for the clarification.